# How many samples are needed for a T-test

Tags: t-test

Reading scientific biological papers I can see that comparing two conditions experiments are often repeated 4-6 times when a T-test is applied (for example cell survival is compared between control and drug-treated cells).

Some papers have as low as 3 replicates, the good ones might go for 7-10 replicates.

What should be a gold standard for a T-test?

Comment: Any "gold standard" would include a *power analysis.*  FWIW, the t-test, when originally proposed 113 years ago, was demonstrated on samples of size four.

Answer (score 7):

There is no particular sample size $n$ that is always best. For each
study you need to take a number of issues into account, and that
process can lead to the required sample size in a given situation.

Let's assume that you are testing at the 5% level, and that you
want the probability (called 'power') of detecting something of interest to be
high---perhaps 80%, 90% or 95%.

Then you need to decide the
amount of difference $\Delta$ between means of control and treatment groups
you want to detect. Also, if your observations have small variability, then
it will be easier to detect important effects than if variability is
large, so you need an educated guess for the standard deviation $\sigma$
of the observations. You will seldom be absolutely sure about $\Delta$ and $\sigma,$
so some guesswork based on previous experiments of the same kind is often
helpful.

With a choice of desired power and a good guess about the ratio of $\Delta$ to $\sigma,$
you are ready to use formulas or computer procedures to find what sample
size $n$ for control and treatment group you should use.

Suppose your significance level is 5% for a two-sided test, desired power is 90%, and that you
want to detect a difference $\Delta$ that is about $1.5\sigma.$
Then a sample size computation gives $n = 11.$

Here is output from Minitab's 'power and sample size' procedure for two-sample
t tests.  Notice that I input $\Delta = 3$ and $\sigma = 2,$ but any choice
with $\Delta/\sigma = 1.5.$ would have given the same sample sizes.

```
Power and Sample Size 

2-Sample t Test

Testing mean 1 = mean 2 (versus ≠)
Calculating power for mean 1 = mean 2 + difference
α = 0.05  Assumed standard deviation = 2

            Sample  Target
Difference    Size   Power  Actual Power
         3      10    0.85      0.886970
         3      11    0.90      0.916899
         3      13    0.95      0.956112

The sample size is for each group.
```

[image]

Most statistical software programs have power and sample size procedures
for a number of different kinds of tests that are in common use. (I happen
to like the output format provided by Minitab.) There are also Internet
sites that have relevant calculators of varying degrees of accuracy and
ease of use.

Comment: Thank you for your very interesting response. This is a very different way to think (probably the right one!). As normally we do experiments is by having 3-5 replicates, we run a T-test and if it is p<0.05 then it is significant. We do not think about how the std is apriori, or power, or anything. We assume all of these are already in consideration in the T-test.  If I want to perform an experiment comparing control vs treatment on cell survival,I decide what the Delta? I shouldn't care about  Delta, just to know if it is statistically significant or not. Can you clarify this point?

Comment: Suppose a change of 5 units is of clinical importance, that the treatment actually provides a change of 7 units, but the variability is so large that 5 replicates in each group does not lead to rejection, you will be led to believe a potentially useful treatment is worthless. You will have wasted resources on an uninformative experiment and lost the opportunity to pursue a treatment that might have been of benefit.// Rejecting the null hypothesis is not the same thing as 'proving' a treatment is is value. The t test doesm't 'consider' anything, works fine when used appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are getting to the point. Normally, we do not know what change we expect or what change is relevant. So we do not have any idea what changes to consider as important. From your posts, I understand you need to know what to expect and the std to calculate the number of replicates. What if you do not know? Imagine you want to know if a drug affects biology. How do you test if you don't know a prior the std (you could calculate this, ok), and what would be an important DELTA?

Comment: I think you must mean that you don't know _exactly_ what difference $\Delta$ is important. I don't know the scale of your responses. If this is a weight loss program, I would guess you would think that 20 pounds a month is an important weight loss, but I doubt you would be interested in 0.5 pounds. Not knowing _exactly_ is no excuse to avoid thinking about important issues leading to a suitable $n.$ // You are spending dollars intended to lead to progress and maybe experimenting on humans who are inconvenienced and possibly put at some some risk. With that power comes some responsibility.

Comment: Totally agree! However, let's say you use a drug looking for some targets. You see some proteins are changing expression. Protein A expressed 1.5 folds, protein B 20 folds (in response to the drug). You repeat the experiment 3 times. Because A std is low, a T-test will make the change statistically significant. B has a big variability and let's say is not.  So, you cannot decide apriori what Delta to pick. Using your reasoning, how would you decide the number of n's for A and B?

Answer (score 0):

Probably BruceET will kill me... but in my work environment the idea is that for a TTest  more than 6 sampkes are needed to be able to apply a T test.

The idea is that assuming a notmal distribution, 7 samples is a decent number to represent the distribution were 2 -3 samples can no represent it .

I know this is not correct and all the Pro here will disagree and they could write numbers and formulas. Sadly there is another reality on where many people who uses these tools but their level of statistics is basic.

If what i said is wrong, many people are doing these wrong. If there is something true here, maybe someone can expand my answer.

Comment: yep! this is similar to what I had in mind. That's why I asked! Thanks for your input!!

Comment: I felt this repeats the OPs question in saying that "this is something that happens in practice", but it isn't an answer as to whether it is *reasonable* to do this; and that reasonable-ness will depend on context (and issues like precision/power, as per BruceET's answer).